# ExternalInterface.call crashes flash for Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, externalinterface

There is a swf file on my website, when i click a button on it. It calls a js function, this function removes this swf and puts another.The problem is it crashes on Chrome.
  I am confused about the problem. These are the cases:
-If i comment out the code which removes swf file and add next swf file, no crash happens.
-If i call javascript function(which is called from swf) from my side, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
Make a test to let the call from the swf return before removing the swf from the DOM. Try something like setTimeout to let the call from the swf return and then let the remove-code be triggered by the timeout.

What kind of crash is it? AS3 exception or chrome crash?